# How to edit ribbon button tooltip

Tags: 2013, ribbon

There is a custom ribbon button **MyButton** declared inside feature and deployed on site.
Now I need to change it's tooltip value in some cases:

- Button **enabled**: **Some text**
- Button **disabled** and **there is** value in web property bag: **Some text**
- Button **disabled** and **there are no** value in web property bag: **Other text**

First, I've tried to get ribbon button object in JavaScript and edit it's properties after page load. Such API wasn't found, though. Actually, I can get button object in the way like:

```
var ribbonPageManager = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
var ribbon = ribbonPageManager.get_ribbon();
var button = ribbon.$38_1.$5_0
{
    Id: "Ribbon.Documents.New.MyButton",
    Alt: "My Button",
    Command: "MyButtonAction",
    LabelText: "My Button",
    Image16by16: "/_layouts/15/mybutton_16.png",
    Image32by32: "/_layouts/15/mybutton_32.png",
    TemplateAlias: "o1",
    ToolTipTitle: "My Button",
    ToolTipDescription: "Some text"
}
```

Second, I've tried to create **PageComponent** but there are no ribbon button properties either.

Next, I've tried to replace **CommandUIDefinition** on server side after changing web property bag value. But it duplicated existing ribbon button instead of replacing. My PowerShell snippet:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite
$xml = New-Object XML;
$xml.Load("C:\CommandUIExtension.xml");
$action = $web.UserCustomActions.Add()
$action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon"
$action.RegistrationType="ContentType"
$action.RegistrationId="0x0101005FFBD71906344882B67C08F40847968B"
$action.Sequence = 10001
$action.Title = "Replace My Button Action"
$action.CommandUIExtension = $xml.OuterXml
$action.Update()
```

Where **CommandUIExtension.xml** contains:

```
<CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.Controls._children">
            <Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.MyButton" 
                TemplateAlias="o1" 
                Command="MyButtonAction"
                LabelText="My Button" 
                ToolTipTitle="My Button" 
                ToolTipDescription="Other text"
                Image16by16="/_layouts/15/mybutton_16.png" 
                Image32by32="/_layouts/15/mybutton_32.png" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="MyButtonAction" CommandAction="javascript: MyButtonAction();" EnabledScript="javascript: MyButtonActionEnable();"/>
    </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

The only solution now is to handle **DOMSubtreeModified** event and to change tooltip text on the go:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    _tooltip = $("#Ribbon\\.Documents\\.New\\.MyButton_ToolTip.ms-cui-tooltip");
    //If tooltip exists and it wasn't modified yet
    if (_tooltip.length > 0 && !_tooltip.data("modified")) {
        if (MyButtonCheck()) {
            _tooltip.data("modified", true);
            _tooltip.find(".ms-cui-tooltip-description").html("Other text");
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any solution to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Enam, It appears that others are using JavaScript to make these type of dynamic changes to the buttons once they load. See: https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/sharepoint-ribbon-designer-programmability.php

Answer (score 0):

It may be resolved by CSS trick.

For example, the "Attach file" ribbon element. In html-code it presents by the following code:

```
<a class="ms-cui-ctl-large" 
   id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile-Large" 
   role="button" 
   aria-describedby="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile_ToolTip" 
   onclick="return false;" 
   href="javascript:;" unselectable="on" mscui:controltype="Button">
   <!--...-->
</a>
```

Here we need the value of property `aria-describedby`: **Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile_ToolTip**

It's a DOM-element Id that's generated for the tooltip: when pointer is over the button, SP generates the following code in the end of `<html>` element:

```
<span class="ms-cui-tooltip" id="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile_ToolTip" role="tooltip" aria-hidden="false" style="left: 256px; top: 156px; width: auto; visibility: visible; position: absolute; -ms-overflow-y: auto; max-height: none; min-width: 250px;" unselectable="on">    
    <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-body" unselectable="on">
        <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-glow" unselectable="on">
            <h1 unselectable="on">Attach file</h1>
            <div class="ms-cui-tooltip-description" unselectable="on">Attaching file in this element.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Tooltip's text is in `<div class="ms-cui-tooltip-description" unselectable="on">` element.

So we can add the following css-code by script editor webpart:

```
<style>
    #Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Actions\.AttachFile_ToolTip .ms-cui-tooltip-description{
        text-indent: -9999px;
        line-height:0;
    }

    #Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Actions\.AttachFile_ToolTip .ms-cui-tooltip-description:after{
        text-indent:0;
        content:'Put your text here';
        display:block;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

For your button it would be:

```
<style>
    #Ribbon\.Documents\.New\.MyButton_ToolTip .ms-cui-tooltip-description{
        text-indent: -9999px;
        line-height:0;
    }

    #Ribbon\.Documents\.New\.MyButton_ToolTip .ms-cui-tooltip-description:after{
        text-indent:0;
        content:'Put your text here';
        display:block;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
</style>
```